# Getting "The service does not allow you to log on anonymously" wcf net.tcp self hosted service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, impersonation

I have a WCF Service hosted in Windows Server with net.tcp binding.
Web API application(ASP.NET MVC .NET 4.5.2) hosted in IIS is calling this service using windows authentication after impersonating using the httpcontext.user context. Both Web API and WCF service are hosted in different machines in the same domain.
If I try to use the WebAPI from the web server machine then everything works fine.

But if we try to access the WebAPI from different machine then I get following error in the WCF Trace logs in the WFC Server machine.

**Exception**

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
The service does not allow you to log on anonymously.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ValidateAnonymityConstraint(WindowsIdentity identity, Boolean allowUnauthenticatedCallers)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptor.CreateClientSecurity(NegotiateStream negotiateStream, Boolean extractGroupsForWindowsAccounts)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptor.OnAcceptUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty&amp; remoteSecurity)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptorBase.AcceptUpgrade(Stream stream)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InitialServerConnectionReader.UpgradeConnection(IConnection connection, StreamUpgradeAcceptor upgradeAcceptor, TimeSpan openTimeout, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OpenAndEnsurePump()
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OpenAndEnsurePump(Object state)
System.Runtime.ActionItem.DefaultActionItem.TraceAndInvoke()
System.Runtime.ActionItem.DefaultActionItem.Invoke()
System.Runtime.ActionItem.CallbackHelper.InvokeWithoutContext(Object state)
System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Anyone had faced similar issue? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try to add windows credentials when calling the service: proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "UserName";
                proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Password";

Comment: I had set the credentials to Windows. Expectation is use the impersonated user for accessing the WCF service.

Comment: Having the same issue and would love to know if you ever found a workaround